# Can I ask people to use the x system for accessibility purposes?

Tags: diacritics

If I was blind and my braille display did not support or show the accented letters in Esperanto with a circumflex or breve above the letter, could I just ask people I'm taking with to use the X or H system for accessibility purposes?

Comment: Just as a note: It's even in the [fundamento](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_angla.html) that the h-system can be used.

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming this is about digital written (presumably online) communication, such as e-mail, textual chat (instant messengers like Telegram, IRC), web forums, etc., as x-system and h-system and braille displays can hardly be used for verbal (i.e. spoken) conversations or printed media.)

I don't know. Could you?

Dad jokes (or teacher jokes) aside, and thus seriously: What would keep you from asking? It's unlikely that you'd offend anyone by asking, even though not all might comply, for the following reasons:

- Not all might be fluent in typing x- or h-system.
- Their spell checking (including auto-correct) might interfere, especially if they've set up their system to also communicate with others or to type texts for professional publishing (where not using the correct diacritics is usually frowned upon).
- Conversion from Esperanto diacritics to x- or h-system is trivial (Just have the computer replace each occurrence — something computers are very good at.), so you can simply (let the computer) perform that transformation on your side. (And if your Braille display can't handle the diacritics otherwise, it makes sense to set up such a conversion on your end, so that you can also read texts that weren't typed only for you.)